# RichTextbox Find

Tags: c#, winforms

I found a good solution for search and highlight text in RichTextbox [LINK](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-find-the-text-and-e92b8d78#content)

And this solution works fine, but I found a very nasty bug, when searching for the last character in any text, such as "Hello World" and if you try to type a letter "d" in search field, program will glitch in endless cycle in here

```
while ((index = this.Find(findWhat, startSearch, findoptions)) > -1)
{
    isfind = true;
    this.SelectionBackColor = highlightColor;
    startSearch = index + 1;
}
```

How to fix this bug? Or maybe help me find another solution how to find and highlight text in `RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is buggy.  You have to add an extra check to ensure it doesn't start the search beyond the end of the text.  Like this:

```
    int max = this.TextLength;
    while (startSearch < max && 
           (index = this.Find(findWhat, startSearch, findoptions)) > -1) {
        isFind = true;
        this.SelectionBackColor = highlightColor; 
        startSearch = index + 1;
    }
```